# Facebook chat doesn't work in Windows Live Messenger 2011

Tags: windows-live-messenger, facebook-chat

I've just installed Windows Live Messenger and connected both my Live and Facebook accounts.

However, I'm unable to see my facebook contacts in the chat panel. When I choose the "Facebook" friends group, I get the message: "There are no contacts in this category." Why?

I remember that last year (around October-November 2010), I was able to chat with my Facebook contacts on Windows Live Messenger 2011 using the built-in chat only (no third-party add-on). Did they remove Facebook chat or am I just doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I left the Windows Live Messenger application alone for about an hour, and I can now see my Facebook contacts. I guess WLM is just very slow when connecting to Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

I had run into the same problem and found another reason Facebook chat fails to work in Windows Live Messenger 2011. If you go offline in the web client of the Facebook chat, then WLM 2011 will not be able to connect to Facebook chat.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Even though it's not the problem I ran into, it might be useful for someone else later.

Comment: Yeah. Hope so!!!